# CSS: Shrink div width with window resize but maintain max-width?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have a large div, 1000px in width, that I want to fix up to expand and contract as follows:

If the user resizes their browser window to a width less then 1000px I want to resize that div accordingly (as if when you use width:100%;).

However, if the user expands their browser window to a width greater then 1000px I want the div to stop growing when it reaches 1000px.

I thought the best way would be to use a combination of `width: 100%` and `max-width: 1000px;` but this is not working for me.

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this?

My full CSS for that div is:

```
#panel
{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 342px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DRmtW/).  Why is is absolutely positioned and why is there a margin?  How do you need it positioned on the page?

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand thanks ill check it out. Margin and position are present for position with other divs on the page

Comment: Can you add some more HTML and update the fiddle?  There's no reason to have the CSS you gave for #panel.  Absolute position without setting top, left, right, or bottom doesn't make sense.  And a margin with absolute positioning does nothing.  If things inside it need to be positioned relative to it, set #panel to `position: relative` and those to `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered media queries? Something like:

```
#panel {
    /* ... */
    width: 100%;
}
@media all and (min-width: 1000px) {
   #panel {
     width: 1000px;
   }
}
```

That would apply a 100% width for screens narrower than 1000px and a fixed width of 1000px for screens at least 1000px wide.

Comment: Just so you know, that's the equivilent of what he has, if you remove the `position` and `absolute` lines.